# File upload from standalone client

Tags: java, apache, file-upload, glassfish

Is is applicable to use Apache FileUpload lib to to upload files to Glassfish v2 server using standalone client? If yes, what are the differences for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I would use HttpClient. And with [HttpClient 4.x](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html), my understanding is that you'll have to use the [HttpMime](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/httpmime/index.html) module for  Multi-part POST.  This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pro/1068132#1068132) provides a code sample.