# FileNotFoundException when trying to upload a recorded video to server from Android app

Tags: java, android, uri

I'm trying to record a video and then upload it to a server upon its completion. Relevant code is here:

```
public void recordVideo(View view){
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, VIDEO_RESULT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VIDEO_RESULT){
        handleCameraVideo(data);
    }
}

private void handleCameraVideo(Intent intent) {
    Uri mVideoUri = intent.getData();
    File vidFile = new File(mVideoUri.getPath());
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    try{
        params.put("video", vidFile);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        //finish upload here, this part isn't relevant to my question
}
```

The problem is that in my `try` block a FileNotFoundException gets thrown, and the stack trace prints out. It seems as though I should be getting the right file: I got most of the code up to the part where I make the File from the Android developer site, so it should work -- which leads me to believe that the problem is at the `File vidFile = new File(mVideoUri.getPath());` line. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It could help [--> Android upload video to remote server using HTTP multipart form data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164398/android-upload-video-to-remote-server-using-http-multipart-form-data) **AND** [-->Uploading audio, video or image files from Android to server](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/03/29/uploading-audio-video-or-image-files-from-android-to-server/)

Comment: Please try to go into further debugging and see to which path the File vidFile finally points to. I guess it is possible that the URI is not converted correctly in a meaningful file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding another question on here that had some code that helped me out:

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Then in my `handleCameraVideo` method:

```
private void handleCameraVideo(Intent intent) {
    Uri mVideoUri = intent.getData();
    String data = getRealPathFromURI(mVideoUri);
    File vidFile = new File(data);
 ....
```

This works and gets me the right file.