# Get file path from Uri from Video Chooser

Tags: android, security, video, uri, android-4.4-kitkat

In my app I start an Intent to pick a video file like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("video/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, kVideoPickerRequestCode);
```

When it comes back i get the Uri like this:

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  if (requestCode == kVideoPickerRequestCode) {
    Uri selectedVideoURI = data.getData();
  }
}
```

This Uri seems to be fine for my VideoView. It plays back the picked video perfectly. But now I'd like to upload the video to a server and therefore need a File.

No matter how i try to convert the Uri to a String-Path, it fails... I read some SO posts on this like 
[How to convert content:// Uri into actual file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154292/how-to-convert-content-uri-into-actual-file-path)
or
[FileNotFoundException when trying to upload a recorded video to server from Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558560/filenotfoundexception-when-trying-to-upload-a-recorded-video-to-server-from-andr)
but it's just not working for me.

Code like this always returns NULL as the path:

```
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Activity activity, Uri contentUri) {
  String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
  Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, proj,  null, null, null);
  int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

My test-device is running Android 4.4.2. Can it be that it's some security issue with KitKat?

Thanks for any helping hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Uri does not necessarily represent a file on the disk. It begins with content:// meaning it is served up by the content provider for that type of file.

You don't actually need to use a file in the filesystem here (although, you can). What you want to do is stream the data from the content provider directly to the server.

There are some good examples - I would try [this one](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/handling-binary-data-with-contentproviders/) for how to do this, in the first section "How to access binary data of existing content providers"

Answer (score -2):

- Hello i know it is too late but recently i found the solution of same problem

  I was also facing the same problem but here is the method

  public static String getPath
  (final Context context, final Uri uri) {

  ```
      if (DEBUG)
          Log.d(TAG + " File -",
                  "Authority: " + uri.getAuthority() +
                          ", Fragment: " + uri.getFragment() +
                          ", Port: " + uri.getPort() +
                          ", Query: " + uri.getQuery() +
                          ", Scheme: " + uri.getScheme() +
                          ", Host: " + uri.getHost() +
                          ", Segments: " + uri.getPathSegments().toString()
                  );

      final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

      // DocumentProvider
      if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

          // ExternalStorageProvider
          else if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
              final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
              final String[] split = docId.split(":");
              final String type = split[0];

              if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                  return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
              }

              // TODO handle non-primary volumes
          }

          // MediaProvider
          else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
              final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
              final String[] split = docId.split(":");
              final String type = split[0];

              Uri contentUri = null;
              if ("image".equals(type)) {
                  contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
              } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                  contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
              } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                  contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
              }

              final String selection = "_id=?";
              final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                      split[1]
              };

              return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
          }
      }

  // MediaStore (and general)

  else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

      // Return the remote address
      if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
          return uri.getLastPathSegment();

      return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
  }
  // File



   else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {


  return uri.getPath();
      }

      return null;
  }
  ```

which i get from this url

--> other methods can be fetched from this FILE UTILS file enjoy coding:) --> and it gets me full video path from the uri hope it helps you :)