# Android : Upload large files using MultipartEntity

Tags: php, android, upload, multipartform-data, multipart

According this answer ["Android upload video to remote server using HTTP multipart form data"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11164451/2624611) I do all steps.

But I don't know how I code for server side! I mean a PHP simple page that serve my reauest foe upload.

And another question is that : YOUR_URL (3rd line of following snippet) must be address of that PHP page?

```
private void uploadVideo(String videoPath) throws ParseException, IOException {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(YOUR_URL);

    FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
    StringBody title = new StringBody("Filename: " + videoPath);
    StringBody description = new StringBody("This is a description of the video");

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);
    reqEntity.addPart("title", title);
    reqEntity.addPart("description", description);
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    // DEBUG
    System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity( );

    // DEBUG
    System.out.println( response.getStatusLine( ) );
    if (resEntity != null) {
      System.out.println( EntityUtils.toString( resEntity ) );
    } // end if

    if (resEntity != null) {
      resEntity.consumeContent( );
    } // end if

    httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code worked properly and PHP code I should use is as simple as this:

```
<?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['videoFile']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['videoFile']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "upload_fail_php_file";
    }
 ?>
```

**NOTE** that videoFile must match exactly with

`reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);`

And the **MOST Important** problem you probably face to, is default value of `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in the server config! As default is too small and when you try to upload large files, the PHP script return : *"upload_fail_php_file"* with no error or exception throwing. **So remember** to set these values as big as enough...

Enjoy coding.