# SimpleMultiPartRequest Android Volley Plus Issue

Tags: android, android-volley, multipart

I am working with an application where i am trying to uploading a file to server with android volley plus SimpleMultiPartRequest, my file gets successfully uploaded to server and I receive file url but with extension xyz.octet-stream, no matter whatever the file is. Below is the code for SimpleMultiPartRequest.

```
SimpleMultiPartRequest request = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(methodType, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {

            uploadSettable.set(s);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            uploadSettable.setException(volleyError);
            Log.v(TAG,volleyError.toString());

        }
    }){

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getFilesToUpload() {

            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("FileData",filePath);
            return map;
        }


        @Override
        public int getMethod() {
            return Method.POST;
        }


        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(PrefUtils.AUTHORIZATION_KEY, "Bearer " + PrefUtils.getString(PrefUtils.PREF_UTILS_ACCESS_TOKEN,"N/A",ArkaaApplicationClass.getInstance().getBaseContext()));
            return map;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(final long transferredBytes, final long totalSize) {

            fileSize = totalSize;
            super.onProgress(transferredBytes, totalSize);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if(progressBarStatus < totalSize) {
                        // performing operation
                        progressBarStatus = (int)((transferredBytes*100)/totalSize);
                        try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                        // Updating the progress bar
                        progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    // performing operation if file is downloaded,
                    if (progressBarStatus >= totalSize) {
                        // sleeping for 1 second after operation completed
                        try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                        // close the progress bar dialog
                        progressBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

    };

    request.setShouldCache(false);
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
     ArkaaApplicationClass.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Comment: Post your relevant code please :-)

Comment: filedata in this request is the path of my file which will upload to server.

Comment: Please take a look at [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity) to see if it could help you or not.

Comment: Didn't Help me at all @ bnk

Answer (score 0):

Use this to send request:

```
// FILE_KEY is your key
// mImagePath is your absolute file path

request.addFile(FILE_KEY,mImagePath);

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(request);
```