# How to fix package: org.apache.http doesn't exist

Tags: android

How to fix package: `org.apache.http` doesn't exist.

Comment: what is the issue ...?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to _Stack Overflow_. Please make an effort to research your technical problems before asking a question, and then when you ask, please write a clear, detailed and intelligible question, whilst refraining from various kinds of begging.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949626/android-m-org-apache-http-entity-fileentity-deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
 android {
       useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
   }
```

Look the Image :

[image]

Comment: i tried but it do not work

Comment: where should i use it in build.gradle (project)

Comment: or in build.gradle(module)

Comment: @PankajChahakar See the image and then Add it.