# How to check the status in json object to get the image from array of object in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-json

First I need to check the json object status `400` if status `400` to get the image otherwise it shows error. I don't how to check status in JSON empty object in android volley. and also I need some help on how to get image by using banner path and banner name.

My Json

```
  {
    "status": "200",
    "requestType": "bannerImages",
    "basePath": "http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/",
    "bannerPath": "http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/cdn-images\/banner\/",
    "response": {
        "data": [
            {
                "banner_id": "37",
                "banner_name": "1457324300894ac3df08bd3648452703d8412f82c2.jpg",
                "banner_link": "",
                "banner_blocked": "0",
                "banner_created": "admin",
                "created_on": "1457324300"
            },
            {
                "banner_id": "36",
                "banner_name": "14573242986be953c24858a3c2d787d57e6b77be1f.jpg",
                "banner_link": "",
                "banner_blocked": "0",
                "banner_created": "admin",
                "created_on": "1457324298"
            },
            {
                "banner_id": "35",
                "banner_name": "1457324295f8d8153fb4f29d3af15276db22435d48.jpg",
                "banner_link": "",
                "banner_blocked": "0",
                "banner_created": "admin",
                "created_on": "1457324295"
            }
        ]
    },
    "request": {
        "postData": [],
        "getData": {
            "type": "bannerImages",
            "result": "json"
        }
    }
}
```

Thank in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: I wanna check status 400 or not how to check that status

Comment: refer my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385467/json-parsing-in-android-studio-1-5-1?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: okay, try like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785236/how-to-check-the-status-in-json-object-to-get-the-image-from-array-of-object-in/36785360#36785360)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get status, try like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String status = jsonObject.optString("status");
```

if you want to parse whole data, I would recommend you to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Answer (score 0):

For easy JSON parsing/manipulating/etc use GSON library at android. Example you can make custom objects and straight create new instance of your custom object from parsing and then just check fields or whatever you need to do.

```
CustomObject object= gson.fromJson(JSON, CustomObject.class);
if(object.bannerPath != null) {
  //Do something
}
```

Here is the [GSON in Github](https://github.com/google/gson)

and here for [GSON tutorial](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

//editing Rohit Arya Code little bit

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String status = jsonObject.optString("status");
if(status.equalIgnorecase("400")){
    try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject("yourResponse");
                   jsonObject1=jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
                    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject1.getJSONArray("data");
                    JSONObject jsonObject2;
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       String banner_name=c.getString("banner_name");
                        Log.e("banner_name",banner_name);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}else{
// don't download
}
```

Comment: I got output. Thanks a lot Amit.I checked the status like what you written here.

Comment: Yw :) if this solution helped you accept the answer :) so that when other person face same problem then it will directly see the correct answer