# How to parse this JSON response in Android?

Tags: android, android-json

I have tried  to parse the data still unable to do .

```
String jsonData = "[{\"id\":\"7\",\"customer_id\":\"1\",\"product_type_id\":\"1\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"ordered_on\":\"2015-12-01\",\"product_consumption_type\":\"general\",\"reason\":\"\",\"productType\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Full Cream Milk\",\"description\":\"\",\"measurement\":\"\"}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"customer_id\":\"1\",\"product_type_id\":\"1\",\"quantity\":\"0\",\"ordered_on\":\"2015-12-02\",\"product_consumption_type\":\"general\",\"reason\":\"\",\"productType\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Full Cream Milk\",\"description\":\"\",\"measurement\":\"\"}}]";
```

---

This is what I've tried so far:

```
try {
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(jsonData, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            try {
                //parsing the value of jsaon array
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject details = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                    String da = details.getString("ordered_on");
                    int qty = Integer.parseInt(details.getString("quantity"));
                    JSONObject prod_det = details.getJSONObject("productType");
                    String na = prod_det.getString("name");
                    ProductType pt = new ProductType(na, qty);
                    Product prod = new Product(da, pt);
                    list.add(prod);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MonthlySummaryActivity.this, "ERROR" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MonthlySummaryActivity.this, "error::" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
loading.hide();
return list;
```

Comment: what's the problem or the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: @Jonathan Darryl i'm not able to retive the data

Comment: Your json string contain an error. I have checked with http://jsoneditoronline.org/. Correct it before parse.

Answer (score 2):

you can parse JSON data in two ways.

1) Create your own parser class.

2) Use library for parsing json string.

**1)** if json string is short then you should go with your own parser class as below.

```
String name;

        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(YOUR JSON STRING);
            JSONObject obj;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                name = obj.getString(KEY_NAME);
                ......
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**2)** use Gson library. for Gson u can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385467/json-parsing-in-android-studio-1-5-1/36386541#36386541).

Answer (score 0):

Hope I could help u.

```
public List<Product> parse(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList();
    JSONArray orderArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
    for (int i = 0, count = orderArray.length(); i < count; i++) {
        JSONObject productJO = orderArray.getJSONObject(i);

        ProductType productType = new ProductType();
        // parse the product type
        JSONObject productTypeJO = productJO.getJSONObject("productType");
        String typeId = productTypeJO.getString("id");
        String name = productTypeJO.getString("name");
        String description = productTypeJO.getString("description");
        String measurement = productTypeJO.getString("measurement");

        productType.setId(typeId);
        productType.setName(name);
        productType.setDescription(description);
        productType.setMeasurement(measurement);

        // parse the product
        String id = productJO.getString("id");
        String customerId = productJO.getString("customer_id");
        String productTypeId = productJO.getString("product_type_id");
        String quantity = productJO.getString("quantity");
        String orderedOn = productJO.getString("ordered_on");
        String productConsumptionType = productJO.getString("product_consumption_type");
        String reason = productJO.getString("reason");

        Product product = new Product();
        product.setId(id);
        product.setCustomerId(customerId);
        product.setProductTypeId(productTypeId);
        product.setQuantity(quantity);
        product.setOrderedOn(orderedOn);
        product.setProductConsumptionType(productConsumptionType);
        product.setReason(reason);
        product.setProductType(productType);

        productList.add(product);
    }
    return productList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and Efficient :** Use Googlle's **Gson library**

- Put this in **build.gradle** file : `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'`
- Now convert the JSON String to a convenient datastrucutre like HashMap in **2 lines** like this.

---

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> myMap = gson.fromJson(JsonString , type);
```

Thank me later :)