# How to create Http Request in Android 6.0

Tags: android, rest, httprequest

I'm trying to find how to do some Http Request in Android 6.0,
Since Android go to the 6.0 version, I can't find anything to help me with the 6.0 changes.

I just wanna do some HTTP request to an REST Api without **any dependencies**

I've done this but its return me 405 instead of 200.

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    public String rest_Url = "https://balblabla" ;
    HttpURLConnection client = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(rest_Url);
        client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (client != null){
            client.setRequestMethod("GET");
           // client.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
            client.setDoOutput(true);
        }

        OutputStream outputPost = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        outputPost.flush();
        if (outputPost!= null){outputPost.close();}

        int responseCode = client.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode != 200){
            String failure = "ECHEC";
            System.out.println(failure);
        }else {
            String success = "BRAVO";
            System.out.println(success);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    finally {
        if(client != null){
            client.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return null;`
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949626/org-apache-http-entity-fileentity-is-deprecated-in-android-6-marshmallow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since apache.http is deprecated from sdk 23 you should use some networking library.

You can either use [Apache Commons](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html) independent package for Android.

**OR**

There are some great libraries available to help you make HTTP requests in Android.

You can use Android's [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) library

or you can use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley) for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add third party library .There is no other option I guess even i faced same problem.
[Apache](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)