# Android: How to resolve <NameValuePair>, BasicNameValuePair, HTTPParams, HttpConnectionParams

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //server able to receive it
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

        post.setEntity();

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949626/org-apache-http-entity-fileentity-is-deprecated-in-android-6-marshmallow

Comment: your better not to use `Apache HttpClient`.. it's  retired... use HttpURLConnection or other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

useLibrary in `build.gradle(Module:app)`, ex:

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.softwareengineer.robot"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
 }
```

Comment: defaultConfig {useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'}

Comment: add httpClient.jar file in libs folder and run the jar file
in build.gradle(Module:app) write
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'