# Can't update the project to Nougat (api 25)

Tags: android, sdk, backwards-compatibility, androidhttpclient, android-7.1-nougat

I have an Android Studio project. The target- and compileSdkVersion for it - is 21. I want to change it to 25.

When I do this, some of the classes of the Android standard library become unavailable. For example **org.apache.http.client.HttpClient**.

here are some screenshots

Android classes before the rise of SDK version. You can see how many classes in org.apache.http.*

[image]

And Android classes after the rise of SDK version:

[image]

I also looked into the android reference, and saw that there is as little classes for 25 api, and (I was confused) for 21 api also. And I noticed that they are the same as I have after upgrade

[image]

Why in the case of 21 api, I have more classes? And how to fix it? Waiting for help. Thanks.

Comment: "Why in the case of 21 api, I have more classes?" -- because [the built-in HttpClient was removed a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949626/org-apache-http-entity-fileentity-is-deprecated-in-android-6-marshmallow). "And how to fix it?" -- there is nothing to fix, other than your code. Google has been advising against using the built-in HttpClient for years.

Answer (score 1):

Since Api 23 (Marshmallow - Android 6.0), the [Apache HTTP Client has been removed](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).

> To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the
>   following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> android {
>     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
> }
> ```