# Why am I getting error in using HttpClient and DefaultHttpClient though I am using sdk22 ? Can these be replaced with other classes?

Tags: android

Why am I getting error in using HttpClient and DefaultHttpClient  though I am using sdk22 ? Can these be replaced with other classes?

[Error while using HttpClient and DefaultHttpClient in android sdk 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmgiy.png)

Comment: Those are not errors. They are deprecation warnings. That being said, you really should be moving to `compileSdkVersion` 25, and [then those classes are simply gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949626/org-apache-http-entity-fileentity-is-deprecated-in-android-6-marshmallow).

Comment: you can use `HttpURLConnection` or a library to make network calls like Retrofit, Volley, OkHttpClient, etc

Answer (score 0):

you can use legacy httpclient like it's described here

[How to add Apache HTTP API (legacy) as compile-time dependency to build.grade for Android M?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade-fo)

or you can download separate apache http client jar and import it in your module dependency

hope it helps.