# Store multiple Image from programatically added ImageView with POST

Tags: android, post, android-bitmap

I have the EditText and Button, where I can put number in EditText of how many ImageView I want to display on my app. Let say, I write 3 then it will display 3 ImageViews on Layout and it works just fine.

I successfully take pictures and display it on those ImageViews.

```
container.removeAllViews();
                for (int i = 1; i <= no; i++) {
                    final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.shelter_row, null);
                    txtV1 = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.txtV1);
                    txtV1.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    addView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            imgLantai = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgLantai);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_10);
                        }
                    });
                    container.addView(addView);
                }
```

I try to get the bitmap and display it on ImageView. It works

```
if(requestCode == CAMERA_10){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
            byte[] byte_arr = output.toByteArray();
            mbitmap10 = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
            imgLantai.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        }
    }
```

By using submit button I try to insert the bitmap to database using POST

```
public void insertFoto(){

    final String URL = "http://www.lineitopkal.com/genset/insert_site.php";

    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.contains("success")) {
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mbitmap01,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data gagal disimpan",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("lantai",mbitmap10);
            return params;
        }
    };

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    rq.add(stringRequest);
}
```

I can't seem store all the images (the mbitmap10 one) in database with POST. Only the latest image was stored. Should I use array to store the image? If so how do I implement it? Or there is other way?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34326822/9130109

Comment: params.put("lantai",mbitmap10);

maybe thats the issue.

Comment: Yes it is....that's why I wonder if there are another way to do it

Comment: Why can't you just add more params??  Are you programming the PHP server side also??

Comment: yes I am @BooberBunz

Comment: How do I add more params if user can create ImageView as much as they want...If I add let say 3 params in code, but user actually need more than 3 ImageViews,,,only the first 3 images stored

Comment: @BrenDonie was my answer helpful at all or have you found a solution. Thanks.

Comment: omg sorry it is...hasn't opened stackoverflow in past few days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: This is general pseudo-code to demonstrate a concept and answer a general question**

1) Put an empty array of bitmaps in your app:

> Bitmap[] allBitmaps = new Bitmap[];

2) Each time that a new image is assigned to one of the image views, add it to the array in the position corresponding to the image view -- allBitmaps[2] = imageView2.getBitmap...

3) Then, when the user clicks submit, do something like this:

```
@Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // int paramNumber = 0;

        // for (bitmap : allBitmaps) {

        // params.put"paramNumber.toString()",bitmap);

        // paramNumber ++;

        // }

        return params;
    }
```