# Spinner Values is not being selected

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have very simple spinnser in which i am showing two value 1=> English 2=> Hebrew

and i restart the whole activity (To change UI) on selecting any value from the spinner but the problem is my activity is only restarting for case 1 only please help me to figure out the problem.

**Here is the code that i am using**

```
languageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (!isFistLaunch) {

                    String email = mEmailEditText.getText().toString();
                    String pass = mPasswordEditText.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("typed_email", email);
                    intent.putExtra("typed_pass", pass);
                    mUserSession.setUserLanguage(lang[position]);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Spinner position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(intent);
                    MainActivity.this.finish();

                } else {
                    isFistLaunch = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

I also put a toast in side it but it only shows for one time...

**Spinner working exactly as i want but only on my device. all of the other devices doesn't show any toast for Hebrew language. They only show Toast for English language.**

can anybody tell me what is the problem here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spTimeName.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

if (!compareValue.equals(null)) {
    int spinnerPosition = dataAdapter.getPosition(compareValue);
    spTimeName.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when activity load which gets first position of array is lang1

```
   Spinner languageSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    String lang[] = {"Select lang","lang1", "lang2"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(JobCardActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lang);
    languageSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            languageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        if(position != 0 || (!lang[position].equals("Select lang"))){

                        Toast.makeText(JobCardActivity.this, "Spinner position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: it is not getting any option on first launch. to avoid this i put a condition.. as you can check in my code

Comment: Not necessary. because Now first time you always get 0'th position

Answer (score 0):

In order to switch language for your app, I suggest you refer to my following code:

```
    protected static void setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        // if not exist, set EN as default
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        final Locale[] availableLocales=Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        if (!(Arrays.asList(availableLocales).contains(locale))) {
            locale = new Locale("en");
        }
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        ((Activity) context).getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                ((Activity) context).getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        // refresh activity to reload resources
        Intent refresh = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
        ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        refresh.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        ((Activity) context).finish();
        ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        context.startActivity(refresh);
    }

    protected static void switchLocale(Context context) {
        Locale current = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
        if (current.getLanguage().equals("he")){
            setLocale(context, "en");
        } else {
            setLocale(context, "he");
        }
    }
```

Then, inside `onClick` of `Button` or `onItemSelected` of `Spinner`..., for example, you can call `switchLocale(mContext);`

P/S: English resources will be stored in `\app\src\main\res\values`, Hebrew resources will be stored in `\app\src\main\res\values-he`

You can read more at [Google's Doc - Supporting Different Languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Bro do you have any idea how to refresh activity contents (layout and text) without restarting activity. and if there is no way to refresh the contents without restarting. then how can i refresh the contents of those activities which are currently in pause state. because when i'll restart them then i'll lost their data and their context. how to overcome this problem. Thanks

Comment: IMO, you can keep data in public static variables.

Comment: i think that's not an efficient solution.

Comment: Another option is using `intent.putExtra` :)

Comment: thats what i am doing right now :P but i think its not a good way too