# Android volley image upload request not working

Tags: java, android, multipart

I have been trying to send request to upload an image from Android App to REST services API, I don't know how to this, can any one help me on this, here are the codes I am trying to use but it says Server side error (500) and on server side the exception is "the request is not a multipart request", please help me I am stuck... :

> Android Code is

```
         Drawable multipartBody = imageView.getDrawable();
         Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)multipartBody).getBitmap();

         ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
         byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

         MultipartRequest multipartRequest = 
    new MultipartRequest(
    APIEndpoints.getURI("UPLOAD_QUESTION_IMG") + newQuestionId[0],
    null,
    "image/jpeg",
    bitMapData,
    new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
             Log.d("Image Upload Was successful!", ""); Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
    }, 
   new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload failed!" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
    }
   );
requestQueue.add(multipartRequest);
```

> Server Side Api is :

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/uploadQuestionImg/{searchId}")
    public ResponseEntity<FileMetadata> uploadFile( @PathVariable String searchId,
                                                    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {}
```

> Server Side stack trace is :

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.assertIsMultipartRequest(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:216)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answer can help ,

[Working POST Multipart Request with Volley and without HttpEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity)

First change of mime type may help.