# Call NVIDIA Digits API from Android application

Tags: java, android, android-volley, nvidia-digits

I am trying to call the running instance of `DIGITS` from a front-end Android mobile application.

DIGITS provides a `REST API` so the curl command would be:

```
curl http://192.168.0.10:5000/models/images/classification/classify_one.json -XPOST -F job_id=20150604-034131-da2c -F image_file=@/path/to/image/desert_0.jpg
```

It is important to mention that the curl tool is using the Content-Type `multipart/form-data` according to `RFC 2388`. This enables uploading of binary files etc.

Many people use Android `Volley` for `HTTP POST` transfer however for multipart/form-data a custom request should be written which turns to be complex.
I am looking to send parameter name/value to the server where value can be either an image or a String.
I have tried so far to adapt the solutions suggested [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity) and [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16803473/3852150) but didn't figure out how to send name/value to the server.

Adapting these answers or suggesting some more up-to-date libraries would be great.

Comment: Did you find solution to your problem? Would be interested to learn