# how to send image file using volley android

Tags: android-volley, multipart

i'm trying to send an image file to server i use volley for making requests when i'm trying to use MultiPartEntityBuilder for sending images it keeps give me deprecated Api i used all the updated libraries but there is no way for sending images without using HttpEntity , need help!

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity to see if it can help you or not