# Android Volley getParams Not Called for Custom Request

Tags: android, rest, post, android-volley

I have created a custom `Volley` `Request` class which extends `Request<NetworkResponse>`. Here is the code for that custom class:

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {
    private final Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
    private final Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
    private final Map<String, String> mHeaders;
    private final Map<String, String> mParams;
    private final String mMimeType;
    private final byte[] mMultipartBody;

    public MultipartRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> params, String mimeType, byte[] multipartBody, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
        this.mHeaders = headers;
        this.mParams = params;
        this.mMimeType = mimeType;
        this.mMultipartBody = multipartBody;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Log.i("MultipartRequest", "headers = " + mHeaders);
        return mHeaders;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Log.i("MultipartRequest", "params = " + mParams);
        return mParams;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return mMimeType;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        return mMultipartBody;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            return Response.success(
                response,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }
}
```

I have inserted the `Log.i` statements within `getHeaders()` and `getParams()` to ensure they are called properly.I create the request as follows:

```
final Map<String, String> volleyParams = new HashMap<>();
volleyParams.put("size", String.valueOf(data.imageSize));
volleyParams.put("width", String.valueOf(data.imageWidth));
volleyParams.put("height", String.valueOf(data.imageHeight));
volleyParams.put("isIndex", updateProfilePhoto ? "1" : "0");

final Context context = this;
final String twoHyphens = "--";
final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
final String boundary = "apiclient-" + System.currentTimeMillis();
final String mimeType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
byte[] multipartBody = new byte[0];

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
try {
    // the first file
    buildPart(dos, data.thumbnailImageArray, "file0");
    // the second file
    buildPart(dos, data.scaledImageArray, "file1");
    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
    // pass to multipart body
    multipartBody = bos.toByteArray();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Map<String, String>  headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("User-Agent", Authentication.getUserAgent());
headers.put("X-XX-API", Authentication.getKey());

MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(BASE_URL + "member/photos", headers, volleyParams, mimeType, multipartBody, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "response: " + response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "statusCode = " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "data = " + error.networkResponse.data);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "headers = " + error.networkResponse.headers);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "notModified = " + error.networkResponse.notModified);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "networkTimeMs = " + error.networkResponse.networkTimeMs);
        }
    });

    MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);
```

The call is performed, however the `getParams()` is never called. How can I ensure the `getParams()` is always called?

Comment: Check the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56498225/3145960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem. You need to override the getBody method and convert all your params to an array of bytes. For example, for a JSON request.

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() {
    if (mParams == null) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        return new Gson().toJson(mParams).getBytes("utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm having issues with combining this with the body of the multipart message. I'm wanting to upload 2 files, with parameters. The body currently contains all the multipart data. Will it work if I just combine the 2 byte arrays? I'm not having any luck combining them at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried overriding getByteData for your files? Look at the last answer of the following link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity#