# How to get Body Response when POST Multipart Request with Volley?

Tags: android-volley, multipartform-data

I'm working with post multipart request from android. And I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity) solution to upload image and succeed perfectly but the query is when I hit my API to upload image to server it returns OK response with a string just like that [image]

I need this body response that is mentioned above. My volley code response only header data. My code is

```
VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

                    Log.wtf("result: ", String.valueOf(response));

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            ...
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
            ...

            return params;
        }
    };
```

Thanks