# How can we request multipart form data using volley in Android

Tags: android, android-volley, multipartform-data

Is it possible to request multipart form with image using volley in android?

Comment: Volley itself is used for light data transfer, There is a library called Volleyplus that can be used for multipart request. 

https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus

Comment: I have read about this volley lib plus, but I am trying to not using another library avoiding memory increase. is there anyway using volley?

Comment: please have a look at this thread, this may help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity