# How to upload Image and Video file using HttpPost in android

Tags: android, file-upload, http-post

I need to upload Image and Video File with multiple parameters like File Name, Description , Height and Width using HttpPost method.

Thanks,
Suggestion appreciated.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164398/android-upload-video-to-remote-server-using-http-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 3):

For uploading a file the efficient way is using HttpPost with multipart/form
**Multipart/form** The file contents are either stored in memory or temporarily on disk. In either case, the user is responsible for copying file contents to a session-level or persistent store as and if desired. The temporary storages will be cleared at the end of request processing


Refer this [Upload Files from Android to a Website/Http Server using Post](http://www.codicode.com/art/upload_files_from_android_to_a_w.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    //Path of the file to be uploaded
    String filepath = params[0];
    File file = new File(filepath);
    ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, SET_MIMETYPE);//"audio/basic"
    try {

        mpEntity.addPart(FILE_NAME, cbFile);
        post.setEntity(mpEntity);
        HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response1.getEntity();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

or also refer this link 
"http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/"
Thanks