# Android- Upload photo to the server

Tags: php, android

the **UploadProduct.class** register a product in my database and upload the photo to my server.
I am trying to upload a file to my server.
 When I execute my app this work perfectly, the product is registered in the database  but in my server , the photo had not been loaded.

When I debug , I put a breakpoint in  `httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);` , the value of `file` atribute is **/storage/emulated/0/aaaa/20150529_104715.jpg**

The path where I save my files is `http://aaaa.com/app/imagenes/` and the path of `upload.php` is `http://aaaa.com/app`

*Here my code:*

**atributes:**

```
private List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
private File file;
private String imageFileName = "";
private String urlImag ="http://aaaa.com/app/imagenes/";
private EditText  etNombreProducto,etDescripcion,etPrecioDia,etPrecioSemana;
private Bitmap bitmap=null;
```

**methods:**

```
public void takePhoto() {



        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        imageFileName = timeStamp  + ".jpg";


        //Creamos el Intent para llamar a la Camara
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //Creamos una carpeta en la memeria del terminal
        File imagesFolder = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "aaaa");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();
        //anadimos el nombre de la imagen
        file= new File(imagesFolder, imageFileName);
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(file);
        //Le decimos al Intent que queremos grabar la imagen
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
        //Lanzamos la aplicacion de la camara con retorno (forResult)
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);


    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //Comprovamos que la foto se a realizado
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Creamos un bitmap con la imagen recientemente
            //almacenada en la memoria
            bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                            "/aaaa/" + imageFileName);
//            //Anadimos el bitmap al imageView para
//            //mostrarlo por pantalla
//            img.setImageBitmap(bMap);
        }
    }


    private boolean uploadFoto(String imag){
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://aaaa.com/app/upload.php");
        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity( );

        ContentBody contentBody = new FileBody(file,"image/jpeg");
        mpEntity.addPart("foto", contentBody);
        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        try {
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            return true;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    private boolean onInsert(){
        String nombreP = etNombreProducto.getText().toString();
        String descripcion = etDescripcion.getText().toString();
        String precioD = etPrecioDia.getText().toString();
        String precioS=etPrecioSemana.getText().toString();
        HttpClient httpclient;

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nombre", nombreP));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("descripcion", descripcion));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("preciodia", precioD));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("preciosemana", precioS));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imagen", urlImag + imageFileName));
        HttpPost httppost;
        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://aaaa.com/app/insertProduct.php");
        // Url del Servidor

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
            return true;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void serverUpdate(){
        if (file.exists())
            new ServerUpdate().execute();
        else
            Toast.makeText(UploadProduct.this, "Debes de hacer una foto",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    class ServerUpdate extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            Boolean b=uploadFoto(imageFileName);
            if(onInsert()&& b)
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(UploadProduct.this, "Exito al subir la imagen",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            else
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(UploadProduct.this, "Sin exito al subir la imagen",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UploadProduct.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Actualizando Servidor, espere..." );
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

**my upload.php**

```
<?php

    $ruta = "app/imagenes/" .basename($_FILES['foto']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $ruta)){
            echo "success";
        } else{
            echo "fail";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164398/android-upload-video-to-remote-server-using-http-multipart-form-data

Comment: thank @zain I see your post but  i think that the problem is in `upload.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In my case , I had to put the absolute path in my php file.*

**upload.php**

```
<?php
// En versiones de PHP anteriores a 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES debe utilizarse en lugar
// de $_FILES.

$uploaddir = '/var/www/vhosts/aaaa.com/httpdocs/app/imagenes/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['foto']['name']);

echo 'bien';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "El archivo es válido y fue cargado exitosamente.\n";
} else {
    echo "¡Posible ataque de carga de archivos!\n";
    echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}

echo 'Aquí hay más información de depurado:';


?>
```

*thanks for your help*

Answer (score 0):

```
    $profilepic = $_FILES ['foto'] ['name'];
    // let if  jpeg image
    $extension='.jpeg';


    function saveImageInServer($profileimage, $email,$extension ) {
        $dir = '/var/www/users';
        if (is_dir ( $dir ) == false) {
            mkdir ( $dir );
        }
        chmod ( $dir, 0777 );
        $target_Path = $dir . "/" . $email . "." . $extension;
        move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ['proiflepic'] ['tmp_name'], $target_Path );
        chmod ( $target_Path, 0777 );
    }
```

Comment: i prove your code! when `upload.php` is executed I get not create any new path. I dont understand the problem. Thanks!