# How do I use androidHttp to upload multipart video to server

Tags: android, http, multipartentity, android-httptransport

According to the android documentations, I should be using `AndroidHttp.HttpTransport` instead of Apache as Apache may not be supported in the future, etc. etc. Does anyone know how to use AndroidHttp for sending multipart data to server? I need to upload a video to server along with title, username, timestamp, etc. Thanks for any help.

With apache, the following code works well for uploading multipart video: [Android upload video to remote server using HTTP multipart form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164398/android-upload-video-to-remote-server-using-http-multipart-form-data?lq=1)

Comment: You should use HttpUrlConnection now. 'uploading multipart video'. No. The video is not multiparted.

Comment: @greenapps will you please convert the code I link to (i.e. `uploadVideo`) to using HttpUrlConnection?