# How do I send a file in Android from a mobile device to server using http?

Tags: android, http, post

In android, how do I send a file(data) from a mobile device to server using http.

Comment: What would the server side code for such a request look like?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Easy, you can use a Post request and submit your file as binary (byte array).

```
String url = "http://yourserver";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
        "yourfile");
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
            new FileInputStream(file), -1);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //Do something with response...

} catch (Exception e) {
    // show error
}
```

Comment: What's the name of the parameter to receive the file in the server?

Comment: @sanrodari: you get file in $_FILES array

Comment: My $_FILES remains empty, I see a lot of other posts using MultipartEntity. Do I need that instead?

Comment: @PoweRoy: It depends. Do you want to send a single file, or multiple files? For multiple files, they must be wrapped into a single container.

Comment: Can you please give a reference to ASP.NET server side code for the above code snippet?

Comment: What should I do if I want to send some data in request body along with file? i.e. send file and also request body?

Comment: @SojharoMangi For that you need to send a MultipartEntity as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24240424

Comment: This should, of course, be done in a worker thread. Otherwise you will get NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: I still not understand how to get name of that parameter

Comment: @DitaAjiPratama I'm not sure I understand your question. When you say the "name of that parameter" do you mean the file name? The file name is not passed in. You'll have to pass it in some other way such as URL parameter or header and artificially retrieve it on the other side. The only standard way around is to use a multipart/form-data which allows passing the file name as a Content-Disposition parameter of each part. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/442512

Comment: @DitaAjiPratama This is a question Java/Android on the client side. I don't think that $_FILES['name'] is in Java. It seems to be PHP (server side). In which case, what I wrote is a valid answer (Content-Disposition parameter for each part) on the client part of the PHP.

Comment: @atishr sorry it was a hypothetical server PHP script. I don't know PHP. But I think this answer could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36863148/442512

Answer (score 16):

This can be done with a HTTP Post request to the server:

```
HttpClient http = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("MyApp");
HttpPost method = new HttpPost("http://url-to-server");

method.setEntity(new FileEntity(new File("path-to-file"), "application/octet-stream"));

HttpResponse response = http.execute(method);
```

Comment: in my case it's throwing an error ,IllegalStateException AndroidHttpClient was never closed, I don't know how to circumvent it.

Comment: Your mileage may vary, but for me this returned an empty set of $_FILES at the server side. Using the MultiPart stuff fixed it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pr

Comment: What is the default `$_FILES['file']` name going to be if you don't set one? is it just `basename($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])`

Answer (score 10):

the most effective method is to use [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

You can use this code to upload a file:

```
// gather your request parameters
File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.png");
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
try {
    params.put("profile_picture", myFile);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {}

// send request
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
        // handle success response
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {
        // handle failure response
    }
});
```

Note that you can put this code directly into your main Activity, no need to create a background Task explicitly. AsyncHttp will take care of that for you!

Comment: how to use this to upload multiple files? note I must wait until the response return to upload the next file, I tried to use this inside for loop but the for loop didn't wait until the response return...

Answer (score 9):

Wrap it all up in an Async task to avoid threading errors.

```
public class AsyncHttpPostTask extends AsyncTask<File, Void, String> {

    private static final String TAG = AsyncHttpPostTask.class.getSimpleName();
    private String server;

    public AsyncHttpPostTask(final String server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(File... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground");
        HttpClient http = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("MyApp");
        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(this.server);
        method.setEntity(new FileEntity(params[0], "text/plain"));
        try {
            HttpResponse response = http.execute(method);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    out.append(line);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            // wr.close();
            try {
                rd.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // final String serverResponse = slurp(is);
            Log.d(TAG, "serverResponse: " + out.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can then call this with:

new AsyncHttpPostTask("http://myserver").execute(new File("myfile"));

Answer (score 4):

the most effective method is to use `org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;`

see this code from the [link](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/tools-and-libs/commons-http-client/http-post-request-with-multipart-entity-body.html) using  `org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;`

```
public class SimplePostRequestTest3 {

  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/HTTP_TEST_APP/index.jsp");

    try {
      FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("C:/ABC.txt"));
      StringBody comment = new StringBody("BETHECODER HttpClient Tutorials");

      MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
      reqEntity.addPart("fileup0", bin);
      reqEntity.addPart("fileup1", comment);

      reqEntity.addPart("ONE", new StringBody("11111111"));
      reqEntity.addPart("TWO", new StringBody("222222222"));
      httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

      System.out.println("Requesting : " + httppost.getRequestLine());
      ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
      String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

      System.out.println("responseBody : " + responseBody);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
  }

}
```

### Added:

[Example Link](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/tools-and-libs/commons-http-client/http-post-request-with-multipart-entity-body.html)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still trying, you could try with retrofit2 [this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-files-to-server-using-retrofit-2-in-android/).