# Sending files using POST with HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, http, post, client-server, httpurlconnection

Since the Android developers [recommend](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) to use the `HttpURLConnection` class, I was wondering if anyone can provide me with a good example on how to send a bitmap "file" (actually an in-memory stream) via POST to an Apache HTTP server. I'm not interested in cookies or authentication or anything complicated, but I just want to have a reliable and logic implementation. All the examples that I've seen around here look more like "let's try this and maybe it works".

Right now, I have this code:

```
URL url;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://example.com/server.cgi");

    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

} catch (Exception e) {
    this.showDialog(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage());
}
finally {
    if (urlConnection != null)
    {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

where showDialog should just display an `AlertDialog` (in case of an invalid URL?).

Now, let's say that I generate a bitmap like so: `Bitmap image = this.getBitmap()` inside a control derived from `View` and I want to send it via POST. What would be the proper procedure to achieve such a thing? What classes do I need to use? Can I use `HttpPost` like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126746/1174378)? If so, how would I construct the `InputStreamEntity` for my bitmap? I would find it revolting to be required to first store the bitmap in a file on the device.

---

I should also mention that I really need to send every unaltered pixel of the original bitmap to the server, so I can't convert it to JPEG.

Comment: Refer [this SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

I have no idea why the `HttpURLConnection` class does not provide any means to send files without having to compose the file wrapper manually. Here's what I ended up doing, but if someone knows a better solution, please let me know.

Input data:

```
Bitmap bitmap = myView.getBitmap();
```

Static stuff:

```
String attachmentName = "bitmap";
String attachmentFileName = "bitmap.bmp";
String crlf = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";
```

Setup the request:

```
HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/server.cgi");
httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty(
    "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + this.boundary);
```

Start content wrapper:

```
DataOutputStream request = new DataOutputStream(
    httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream());

request.writeBytes(this.twoHyphens + this.boundary + this.crlf);
request.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
    this.attachmentName + "\";filename=\"" + 
    this.attachmentFileName + "\"" + this.crlf);
request.writeBytes(this.crlf);
```

Convert `Bitmap` to `ByteBuffer`:

```
//I want to send only 8 bit black & white bitmaps
byte[] pixels = new byte[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.getWidth(); ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.getHeight(); ++j) {
        //we're interested only in the MSB of the first byte, 
        //since the other 3 bytes are identical for B&W images
        pixels[i + j] = (byte) ((bitmap.getPixel(i, j) & 0x80) >> 7);
    }
}

request.write(pixels);
```

End content wrapper:

```
request.writeBytes(this.crlf);
request.writeBytes(this.twoHyphens + this.boundary + 
    this.twoHyphens + this.crlf);
```

Flush output buffer:

```
request.flush();
request.close();
```

Get response:

```
InputStream responseStream = new 
    BufferedInputStream(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream());

BufferedReader responseStreamReader = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));

String line = "";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
}
responseStreamReader.close();

String response = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Close response stream:

```
responseStream.close();
```

Close the connection:

```
httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
```

PS: Of course I had to wrap the request in `private class AsyncUploadBitmaps extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, String>`, in order to make the Android platform happy, because it doesn't like to have network requests on the main thread.

Comment: Finally a perfectly explained answer for this question! Thank you! BTW, I just found this article from the Android Developers Blog (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) where they suggest using HTTPURLConnection over the Apache HTTPClient. Cheers!

Comment: PS: According to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), ` [error] => 3` means that "the uploaded file was only partially uploaded", so I can assume that there are some buffering issues, but I have no idea how to debug / fix something like this.

Comment: See my comment just above. You need to add them to the `url` variable, like so: `URL url = new URL("http://example.com/?param1=val1&param2=val2");`. You can add as many as you wish (although I think there are some limits).

Comment: Perfect answer! I suggest to take a look at [this w3.org docs about forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)

Answer (score 70):

I actually found a better way to send files using HttpURLConnection using MultipartEntity

```
private static String multipost(String urlString, MultipartEntity reqEntity) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Content-length", reqEntity.getContentLength()+"");
        conn.addRequestProperty(reqEntity.getContentType().getName(), reqEntity.getContentType().getValue());

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        reqEntity.writeTo(conn.getOutputStream());
        os.close();
        conn.connect();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return readStream(conn.getInputStream());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "multipart post error " + e + "(" + urlString + ")");
    }
    return null;        
}

private static String readStream(InputStream in) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Assuming you are uploading an image with bitmap data:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = ...;
    String filename = "filename.png";
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
    ContentBody contentPart = new ByteArrayBody(bos.toByteArray(), filename);

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    reqEntity.addPart("picture", contentPart);
    String response = multipost("http://server.com", reqEntity);
```

And Voila! Your post data will contain picture field along with the filename and path on your server.

Comment: I notice you're not calling conn.disconnect(), is it intentional?

Comment: @MihaiTodor You will want to compress the bitmap into a File to reduce the amount of data passed over network anyway.

Comment: @stealthcopter Well, that is up to the developer, but my method lets people preserve the original pixels of the bitmap. In my use case (256x256 bitmaps for a demo), zipping the bitmap wasn't worth the hassle, but for a real application, it will definitely be a good practice to use some archiving mechanism.

Comment: you should call setFixedLengthStreamingMode(reqEntity.getContentLength())
instead of setting the Content-Length header directly. This way your data isn't buffered before sending on the socket (at least on newer devices, on android 2.3 or less it seems they get buffered anyways). I fixed the buffering issue on older devices by using okhttp as the transport and that works.

Comment: too bad MultipartEntity is not bundled with Android SDK

Comment: @mente It is bundled with the httpmime.  I use this as a Gradle dependency: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1.1

Comment: Works fine, but I had to comment `conn.addRequestProperty("Content-length", reqEntity.getContentLength()+"")` because it was generating a malformed request with a duplicated "Content-length:" header with value "-1". Apache was replying 400 Bad Request even before the upload was completed. Content-length is set automatically by HttpURLConnection.

Comment: This its part of android now as com.android.internal.http.multipart.MultipartEntity so the gradle dependency is not needed.

Answer (score 19):

The solution of **Jaydipsinh Zala** didn't work for me, I don't know why but it seems to be close to the solution.

So merging this one with the great solution and explanation of **Mihai Todor**, the result is this class that currently works for me. If it helps someone:

*MultipartUtility2V.java*

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class MultipartUtilityV2 {
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private DataOutputStream request;
    private final String boundary =  "*****";
    private final String crlf = "\r\n";
    private final String twoHyphens = "--";

    /**
     * This constructor initializes a new HTTP POST request with content type
     * is set to multipart/form-data
     *
     * @param requestURL
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MultipartUtilityV2(String requestURL)
            throws IOException {

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);

        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty(
                "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + this.boundary);

        request =  new DataOutputStream(httpConn.getOutputStream());
    }

    /**
     * Adds a form field to the request
     *
     * @param name  field name
     * @param value field value
     */
    public void addFormField(String name, String value)throws IOException  {
        request.writeBytes(this.twoHyphens + this.boundary + this.crlf);
        request.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\""+ this.crlf);
        request.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + this.crlf);
        request.writeBytes(this.crlf);
        request.writeBytes(value+ this.crlf);
        request.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a upload file section to the request
     *
     * @param fieldName  name attribute in <input type="file" name="..." />
     * @param uploadFile a File to be uploaded
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        request.writeBytes(this.twoHyphens + this.boundary + this.crlf);
        request.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                fieldName + "\";filename=\"" +
                fileName + "\"" + this.crlf);
        request.writeBytes(this.crlf);

        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(uploadFile.toPath());
        request.write(bytes);
    }

    /**
     * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
     *
     * @return a list of Strings as response in case the server returned
     * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String finish() throws IOException {
        String response ="";

        request.writeBytes(this.crlf);
        request.writeBytes(this.twoHyphens + this.boundary +
                this.twoHyphens + this.crlf);

        request.flush();
        request.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream responseStream = new
                    BufferedInputStream(httpConn.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader responseStreamReader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            responseStreamReader.close();

            response = stringBuilder.toString();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution which only works for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: but why you don't flush at the end of addFilePart() ?
i saw you did flushing for the end of addFormField() . @Georgevik

Comment: How to use this in another class? pls show example

Answer (score 3):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33149413/6481542 got me 90% of the way with uploading large files to a development Django server, but I had to use [setFixedLengthStreamingMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFixedLengthStreamingMode%28int%29) to make it worked.  That requires setting the Content-Length before writing the content, thus requiring a fairly significant rewrite of the above answer.  Here's my end result

```
public class MultipartLargeUtility {
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private final int maxBufferSize = 4096;
    private long contentLength = 0;
    private URL url;

    private List<FormField> fields;
    private List<FilePart> files;

    private class FormField {
        public String name;
        public String value;

        public FormField(String name, String value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private class FilePart {
        public String fieldName;
        public File uploadFile;

        public FilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile) {
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
            this.uploadFile = uploadFile;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This constructor initializes a new HTTP POST request with content type
     * is set to multipart/form-data
     *
     * @param requestURL
     * @param charset
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MultipartLargeUtility(String requestURL, String charset, boolean requireCSRF)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";
        url = new URL(requestURL);
        fields = new ArrayList<>();
        files = new ArrayList<>();

        if (requireCSRF) {
            getCSRF();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds a form field to the request
     *
     * @param name  field name
     * @param value field value
     */
    public void addFormField(String name, String value)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String fieldContent = "--" + boundary + LINE_FEED;
        fieldContent += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"" + LINE_FEED;
        fieldContent += "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset + LINE_FEED;
        fieldContent += LINE_FEED;
        fieldContent += value + LINE_FEED;
        contentLength += fieldContent.getBytes(charset).length;
        fields.add(new FormField(name, value));
    }

    /**
     * Adds a upload file section to the request
     *
     * @param fieldName  name attribute in <input type="file" name="..." />
     * @param uploadFile a File to be uploaded
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();

        String fieldContent = "--" + boundary + LINE_FEED;
        fieldContent += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + LINE_FEED;
        fieldContent += "Content-Type: "
                + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName) + LINE_FEED;
        fieldContent += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + LINE_FEED;
        fieldContent += LINE_FEED;
        // file content would go here
        fieldContent += LINE_FEED;
        contentLength += fieldContent.getBytes(charset).length;
        contentLength += uploadFile.length();
        files.add(new FilePart(fieldName, uploadFile));
    }

    /**
     * Adds a header field to the request.
     *
     * @param name  - name of the header field
     * @param value - value of the header field
     */
    //public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
    //    writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
    //    writer.flush();
    //}

    /**
     * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
     *
     * @return a list of Strings as response in case the server returned
     * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
        String content = "--" + boundary + "--" + LINE_FEED;
        contentLength += content.getBytes(charset).length;

        if (!openConnection()) {
            return response;
        }

        writeContent();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }
        return response;
    }

    private boolean getCSRF()
            throws IOException {
        /// First, need to get CSRF token from server
        /// Use GET request to get the token
        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.getContent();
        conn.disconnect();

        /// parse the returned object for the CSRF token
        CookieStore cookieJar = cookieManager.getCookieStore();
        List<HttpCookie> cookies = cookieJar.getCookies();
        String csrf = null;
        for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {
            Log.d("cookie", "" + cookie);
            if (cookie.getName().equals("csrftoken")) {
                csrf = cookie.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (csrf == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Unable to get CSRF");
            return false;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Received cookie: " + csrf);

        addFormField("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrf);
        return true;
    }

    private boolean openConnection()
            throws IOException {
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);    // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        //httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
        httpConn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(contentLength);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(httpConn.getOutputStream());
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
        return true;
    }

    private void writeContent()
            throws IOException {

        for (FormField field : fields) {
            writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + field.name + "\"")
                    .append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                    LINE_FEED);
            writer.append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append(field.value).append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.flush();
        }

        for (FilePart filePart : files) {
            String fileName = filePart.uploadFile.getName();
            writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append(
                    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + filePart.fieldName
                            + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                    .append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append(
                    "Content-Type: "
                            + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                    .append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.flush();

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePart.uploadFile);
            int bufferSize = Math.min(inputStream.available(), maxBufferSize);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            inputStream.close();
            writer.append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.flush();
        }

        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Usage is largely the same as in the above answer, but I've included CSRF support that Django uses by default with forms

```
boolean useCSRF = true;
MultipartLargeUtility multipart = new MultipartLargeUtility(url, "UTF-8",useCSRF);
multipart.addFormField("param1","value");
multipart.addFilePart("filefield",new File("/path/to/file"));
List<String> response = multipart.finish();
Log.w(TAG,"SERVER REPLIED:");
for(String line : response) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Upload Files Response:::" + line);
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, how do i read the posted file at the receiving end?  i want to read the file and write to disk.

Answer (score 2):

based on Mihai's solution, if anyone has the problem of saving images on the server like what happened on my server. change the Bitmap to bytebuffer part to :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,bos);
        byte[] pixels = bos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but you might try using PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream.  It might look something like:

```
final Bitmap bmp = … // your bitmap

// Set up Piped streams
final PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
final PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream(pos);

// Send bitmap data to the PipedOutputStream in a separate thread
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, pos);
    }
}.start();

// Send POST request
try {
    // Construct InputStreamEntity that feeds off of the PipedInputStream
    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(pis, -1);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true);
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did for uploading photo using post request.

```
public void uploadFile(int directoryID, String filePath) {
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    String upload_url = BASE_URL + UPLOAD_FILE;
    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

    byte[] data = bao.toByteArray();

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(upload_url);
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    try {
        // Set Data and Content-type header for the image
        FileBody fb = new FileBody(new File(filePath), "image/jpeg");
        StringBody contentString = new StringBody(directoryID + "");

        entity.addPart("file", fb);
        entity.addPart("directory_id", contentString);
        postRequest.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        // Read the response
        String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.e("response after uploading file ", jsonString);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error in uploadFile", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** This code requires libraries so Follow the instructions [here](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/using-newer-version-of-httpclient-like-4-1-x/) in order to get the libraries.

Comment: It's good to know that there is a way to make use of the latest version of `HttpClient` (your link is outdated. Use [this one](http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/) instead), which the Android guys are keeping only for backwards compatibility, rather than use the built in `HttpURLConnection`. On the other hand, it looks like it requires more work to set it up, so maybe it's not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions above and none worked for me out of the box.

However http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-post-http-request. Line 6 POST Multipart Request worked within seconds

```
public void whenSendMultipartRequestUsingHttpClient_thenCorrect() 
  throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com");

    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.addTextBody("username", "John");
    builder.addTextBody("password", "pass");
    builder.addBinaryBody("file", new File("test.txt"),
      ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "file.ext");

    HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
    httpPost.setEntity(multipart);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    client.close();
}
```