# Upload large file with progress bar and without OutOfMemory Error in Android

Tags: android, file-upload, out-of-memory, multipartform-data

I am having some problem while uploading large video file(upto 150MB)

1.When I use this code [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18821095/3499971) .I able to upload small file with progress bar ,but as my file is large so android give me **OutOfMemory Error**.

2.If I use this code [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5220954/2385424). i am able to upload large file(this is really a good solution) but don't know how to show progess(like 20% complete or 80% complete and so on).so Please guide me.

Comment: Have you tried to use more than 200 chunks in the code from the first link?

Comment: yes I tried upto 500 chunks but not worked so tried using Link2

Comment: @VibhorBhardwaj : Even 500 chunks needs a buffer of around 300KB for a 150MB file. I'd probably go with at least 2000 chunks which would take the buffer size down to  around 75KB.

Comment: @Squonk I have tried chunks size 200000 but it's still it gives Out of memory Error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally I got solution of my question I want to share it ...

1.First solution **[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18821095/2385424)** This solution is ok with small files like image upload upto 15MB .But I could not get rid from OutOfMemory error if file is very large.

2.Second solution(**[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5220954/2385424)**) is really a good solution and for showing progress bar I used a custom MultipartEntity class. Code is here:

```
    import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;

    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;

    public class CustomMultiPartEntity extends MultipartEntity

{

    private final ProgressListener listener;

    public CustomMultiPartEntity(final ProgressListener listener)
    {
        super();
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public CustomMultiPartEntity(final HttpMultipartMode mode, final ProgressListener listener)
    {
        super(mode);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public CustomMultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode mode, final String boundary, final Charset charset, final ProgressListener listener)
    {
        super(mode, boundary, charset);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException
    {
        super.writeTo(new CountingOutputStream(outstream, this.listener));
    }

    public static interface ProgressListener
    {
        void transferred(long num);
    }

    public static class CountingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream
    {

        private final ProgressListener listener;
        private long transferred;

        public CountingOutputStream(final OutputStream out, final ProgressListener listener)
        {
            super(out);
            this.listener = listener;
            this.transferred = 0;
        }

        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
        {
            out.write(b, off, len);
            this.transferred += len;
            this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
        }

        public void write(int b) throws IOException
        {
            out.write(b);
            this.transferred++;
            this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
        }
    }
}
```

And my activity code is

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import com.example.fileupload.CustomMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private ProgressBar pb;
    private final String filename = "/mnt/sdcard/vid.mp4";
    // private final String filename = "/mnt/sdcard/a.3gp";
    private String urlString = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/FileUploadServlet1/UploadServlet";
    private TextView tv;
    long totalSize = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
        tv.setText("init");
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    }

    private class Uploadtask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pb.setProgress(0);
            tv.setText("shuru");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return upload();
        }

        private String upload() {
            String responseString = "no";

            File sourceFile = new File(filename);
            if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
                return "not a file";
            }
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlString);


            try {
                CustomMultiPartEntity entity=new CustomMultiPartEntity(new ProgressListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void transferred(long num) {
                        publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));                       
                    }
                });

                entity.addPart("type", new StringBody("video"));
                entity.addPart("uploadedfile", new FileBody(sourceFile));
                totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                httppost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            }

            return responseString;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            tv.setText(result);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Uploadtask().execute();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure what you have done indicating actual file upload progress OR file read progress from file system which is very quick ?

Comment: Hello @VibhorBhardwaj Thank you. Your code perfectly work in mp3 file uploading. but it cann't play audio after uploading on server side. event it can not play in browser  also.

Comment: MultipartEntity is deprecated. We need an updated version of this code.