# File uploading Not getting regular callback response?

Tags: android, file-upload, progress-bar, http-put, chunked

I am trying to upload a 20mb video file to cloud using http put method. File is uploading as byte array format. To show the progress of upload, I add progress callback with entity. But now I'm getting the call back response after uploading the full file and response show 100.00.

How do I get the callback after in every 10kb uploading?

Here is my code:

```
  byte[] videoBytes = ous.toByteArray();
  httput.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(videoBytes));

  httput.setEntity(new ProgressHttpEntityWrapper(httput.getEntity(), progressCallback));
```

Comment: try with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22885540/942224

Comment: here i am not using a multipart method.