# In Android, how to upload an image and string data to a website

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-networking

I am making an application in android, in my application i need to provide user the functionality of uploading an image with GPS location data. After many searches on Google, i was not able to find any of the working code that would upload image from Android to server. I want to use 'HttpURLConnection' and want php coding in server side. plz any body can provide me a sample code with explanation for both java class and php coding.

Comment: plz any body can explain step by step what happen in the background when we uploading. as a ex :- "outPutStream.write();" will upload the bytes or what happen. and what php file expect from the client. if you can explain exhaust things , may be i can write my own code as i want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MultipartEntity` to upload the image to the server.

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
```

Comment: plz read the question, after get clear idea post a helpful answer. if not don't post any thing

Answer (score 0):

One really good code is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11826317/1234007. You have to use multi-part to send data with POST.
PHP is pretty good in handling. Check out the official documentation of PHP for the working code to handle the POST data that has the file and the image http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

All the best

Answer (score 0):

```
For android :[enter link description here][1]

mport java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UploadImage extends Activity {
    InputStream inputStream;
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_upload);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);         
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
            ArrayList<namevaluepair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<namevaluepair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",image_str));

            try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.0.23/Upload_image_ANDROID/upload_image.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
                Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "Response " + the_string_response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch(Exception e){
                  Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }
        }

        public String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{

             String res = "";
             StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
             inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
             int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength(); //getting content length…..
             Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "contentLength : " + contentLength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             if (contentLength < 0){
             }
             else{
                    byte[] data = new byte[512];
                    int len = 0;
                    try
                    {
                        while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
                        {
                            buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len)); //converting to string and appending  to stringbuffer…..
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        inputStream.close(); // closing the stream…..
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    res = buffer.toString();    


             Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "Result : " + res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //System.out.println("Response => " +  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
             }
             return res;
        }
}
```