# how to send Android asset file over httpurlconnection?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have a text/plain file in asset folder. I want to send this file over httpurlconnection as a string or suggest. how to do that.
My code is as below:

```
  java.net.URL url = new URL("https://xx.xx.xx.xxx");
                HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory());
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(15*10000);
                urlConnection.connect();

                AssetManager assetManager = MainActivity.ctx.getAssets();
                InputStream requestXML = assetManager.open("requestdump");

                String requestString = convertStreamToString(requestXML);

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                convertStreamToString(in);
```

Please suggest how to send asset text file over httpurlconnection?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the problem in your current code?

Comment: I don't no how to send String requestString = convertStreamToString(requestXML); over httpurlconnection?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection

Comment: can't we send simple string over httpurlconnection?

Comment: yesyou can but you mentioned to pass the file

Comment: Sorry for mistake. I have long string, I want to send that string? How to do that?

Comment: Then what has this to do with sending asset files? Please change your subject.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to send string

```
URL url = new URL("http://yoururl.com");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstParam", paramValue1));

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();


private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: namevalue pairs can send long string?

Comment: ok thank you, I am getting an error line here writer.write(getQuery(params));