# Sending something to a server - Updating android code

Tags: android, server

I would like to send a file to a server. Currently the code I use includes deprecated classes. How can I update the code to be uptodate?

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), params[0]);
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(server);

            InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(file), -1);
            reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
            reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            //Do something with response...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this library : retrofit
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

I use it on my project right now and it helps me a lot with my http requests.

Moreover the documentation is really good.