# Java Multipart POST returns MediaTypeNotSupported from WebApi server

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net-web-api2, multipartform-data

I'm using the 'MultipartUtil' class as described in the first answer of the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection).

I've changed the constructor, by adding additional lines, as follows:

```
public MultiPartUtil(String requestURL, String charset) throws IOException {
    this.charset = charset;

    // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
    boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

    URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MTApp");

    outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset), true);
}
```

And the code to upload a file is:

```
MultiPartUtil multipart = new MultiPartUtil(url, "UTF-8");
multipart.addFilePart("archive", new File("archivefile.zip"));
multipart.finish();
```

On the server side, I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public void upload()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, "This request is not properly formatted"));
    }

    //Process file here...
}
```

What might I be missing in the Java code that does not allow the file to be accepted?

Comment: Can you please try to change the boundary to render like ---1234567--- instead of ===1234567===? Because tokens are not allowed in http header parameters.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Add as answer so I can mark it!

Comment: Fixed right :) thanks

Comment: For multipart boundary, IMO, you can read http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try to change the boundary to render like ---1234567--- instead of ===1234567===?

Because tokens are not allowed in http header parameters.