# Sending a binary file in Android using the UrlConnection class

Tags: android

I want to send a binary file in Android using UrlConnection class. I've found the code snippets such as here [Sending files using POST with HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection)
but I wonder, hasn't anything changed since then to make it easier? Because code there looks pretty complicated for such a simple thing which many developers need.

And I don't want to use any third-party libraries.

Comment: The question can be reduced to: "I wish this were easier, but I refuse to use tools which make it easier." -- Sorry, nobody can help you with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending files using POST with HttpURLConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make it easier,you think that using the thrid-party library should be a good idea.In fact,google provide a library called "volley",it is easy to use.of course,if you want to use native method,you just do it.