# how to upload an image to server in android

Tags: android, image, rest

I am using `params.put` to post the `strings` to the `server`. But how do I post an image which is saved in the variable `imgPreview`.

comp_logo_id is the image field in Rest Api.

Here is My code:

```
            params.put("title", title);
            params.put("comp_logo_id", comp_logo_id);
            params.put("company_name", company_name);
            params.put("industry_selected", industry_selected);
```

Comment: You need to upload the image file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection

Comment: send image as a file.

Comment: See here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356031/unable-to-post-base64-converted-image-to-rest-service/35356630#35356630

Comment: you want to send image using Base64 or Multipart ? and variable saved in imgPreview is bitmap or file ? Please do clarify that.  @Nikita

Answer (score 0):

You must convert image to base64 and upload to server .
In server convert base64 to image .

```
  public String getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
        byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
        // get the base 64 string
        String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);

        return imgString;
   }
   String encodedImageData =getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(your bitmap);
   params.put("comp_logo_id", encodedImageData );
```