# android HTTP request with post data

Tags: java, android, http-request

Alright so I have the following situation, I got a java app, where users can login, once they do it will generate a random key, I wish to send this key to my website using http requests.

On the web side I will insert it into the database for later use, this is already working.

Now at this moment I am very stuck with the java side. I am using the following code to try the http request:

```
private void startRegistration(String username, String password) {

    String myRandomString = randomString(6);
    String deviceId = "abc";
    startToast(myRandomString);

    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        insertDevice(myRandomString, deviceId);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void insertDevice(String randomString, String deviceId) throws IOException {

//        String urlParameters  = "key=" + randomString + "&device_id="+ deviceId;
//        byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
//        int    postDataLength = postData.length;
    String request        = "http://website.com/test";
    URL    url            = new URL( request );

    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput( true );
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
        conn.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
//            conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
        conn.setUseCaches( false );

    try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
//            wr.write( postData );
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "test", duration);
        toast.show();
       }
   }
```

On the web side I have a route set to catch this request and simple throws a log::info so I can check if the request even ever gets there, this looks like follow:

```
public function create() {

    Log::info('I got here, hurray!');
}
```

now when I hit the URL in my browser I can see the log appearing, when I use my app, I don't. But there are no errors thrown either.

At the end I'd like to use a POST request and send both the random key, and device ID to the website. any help is much appreciated

Comment: you can use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) Library. It will make your task much easier that way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection following link will help you

Comment: you don't seem to be calling `conn.connect()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting up the connection but you're not triggering the request. You can perform the request by calling `conn.connect()` or "operations that depend on being connected" ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect--))

Here's an example of a POST request:

```java
public void insertDevice(String randomString, String deviceId) {

    String request = "http://website.com/test";
    URL url = new URL(request);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    String urlParameters = "key=" + randomString + "&device_id=" + deviceId;
    byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
        os.write(postData);
    }

    conn.connect();

    // Get response code, e.g. 200.
    // conn.getResponseCode();

    // Read server response data with conn.getInputStream() or conn.getErrorStream().

    conn.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Sadly this is still not popping my logs on the web server, but no errors are thrown either.

Comment: @killstreet not even a fixed version o GET hit the server?

Comment: never mind, it was working just the server log had a little delay, you are amazing :) thank you so much!