# Convert curl request to java request

Tags: java, file, curl, httpurlconnection

I need to create http request to google web store for upload items.

I did it in curl and it worked.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer Mytoken"  -H "x-goog-api-version: 2" -X POST -T /Users/mac/Downloads/file_name_3.25.10.zip -v https://www.googleapis.com/upload/chromewebstore/v1.1/items
```

I want to know how to pass -T file value.
This is my code.

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/chromewebstore/v1.1/items");
Map<String, String> params  = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("FILE",filePath);
Map<String, String> requestPropertys  = new HashMap<String, String>();
requestPropertys.put("Authorization","Bearer " + 
GoogleWebStoreDeveloperAuthService.getAccess_token());
requestPropertys.put("x-goog-api-version","2");
requestPropertys.put("Accept","*/*");
content = NetworkUtil.crossApplicationRequestPost(url, params, requestPropertys);
```

public static  String crossApplicationRequestPost(URL url, Map params, Map requestPropertys ) {

```
    String result = null;

    String param = getQueryString(params);
    param = addHashQuery(param);

    /* End preparing params */
    byte[] postData = param.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    int postDataLength = postData.length;

    log.info(" url :"+url);

    try {

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        for (Entry<String, T> entry : requestPropertys.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            connection.setRequestProperty(key, value.toString()); 

        }
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",Integer.toString(postDataLength));
        connection.setUseCaches(false);



        try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.write(postData);
        } 

        log.info(" crossApplicationRequestPost :"+connection.getResponseCode());

        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            result = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            inputStream.close();
        } else {
            log.severe("try fails. Connect to:" + url.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection) you can get the solution for uploading a file using multipart POST HTTP request.

Aside from that, I really recommend you to use some type of helper to help you to make your requests easier. There are plenty of them, but a popular one (and with a lot of documentation) is [Square's OKHTTP library](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)