# Input Stream to Output Stream

Tags: java

I have a problem with my Post of a file to a REST API. The `documentInputStream` comes from a previous function to get the InputStream of a file and it works (it writes the file to my filesystem.

I also checked while debugging and `documentInputStream` has `count = 35125` which is my file size (35Kb)

But the server is not getting any file. (This is not a server issue because it works with postman).

Any help?

```
  // Send document
    HttpURLConnection submitConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(submitURL).openConnection();
    submitConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    submitConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    submitConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
    String boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";
    submitConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    submitConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test Agent");

    // Get output stream
    DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(submitConnection .getOutputStream()); 

    // Write file input stream to the connection stream
    IOUtils.copy(documentInputStream, dataStream);
    // Flush
    dataStream.flush();

    // Get the response 
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(submitConnection.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Any idea why? What am I missing?

Comment: this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection

Comment: What's the difference? And MultipartEntity is deprecated...

Comment: the difference is that you're using IOUtils for some reason. try using OutputStream instead

Comment: I was using IOUtils to pass the inputstream of the file to the outputstream

Comment: so have you tried preparing the file wrapper and sending it directly to OutputStream without IOUtils?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: you may save the file bytes from "documentInputStream" into a buffer first, then send that buffer to outputstream. I don't mean that you should send it that way. For now this is done for the sake of testing