# Upload a file programmatically to a servlet

Tags: java, file-upload, httpurlconnection

I need to call a servlet via another Java file not via UI.  I need to send a csv file along with the request. How can I send the file along with the request which I can access in the servlet.

```
        File myFile = new File("c:\\myfile.csv");
        String strFormURL = "http://localhost:8080/Forms/MyFacesServlet/";
        url = new URL(strFormURL);

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Please advice how the file (myFile) can be passed along with the servlet call. So that I can access the file in Servlet and call a service to validate the file content.

Comment: Can you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection

Comment: See "Uploading files" section of abovelinked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. Could you please share how the file can be read in Servlet as well? I can't see the same as request.getParameter("file name");

Comment: Just click the link behind *"Also see this answer for examples of both the FileUpload and the Servelt 3.0 approaches."* in the bottom of "Uploading files" section of abovelinked duplicate.