# send Jpeg via post in android?

Tags: php, android, http, post, httprequest

Iv'e seen simaliar questions but I didn't understand it.
How can I deliver an captured image (bitmap) to my server via http-post in android(java)?
How should the server side php look like?

Thank you,

Boaz

Answer (score 0):

It would look exactly as if you were accepting input from another script. The posted image will be in PHP's $_FILES array, and you can treat it as you would normally.

Comment: yes, but the bigger question was how i make it in the client's side?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126625/how-to-send-a-file-in-android-from-mobile-to-server-using-http

Comment: OK, i have pasted the code in the link below to my application but how should the server side exactly look-like?