# define opendatabase string parameter while getting path from external sd card

Tags: android, sqlite

```
//this is my handler class


  public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;    
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "feedbackDB.db"; 
  private static final String TABLE_FEEDBACK = "feedback";

  public DBHandler(Context context) {

       super(context,context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()+DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }



  public void openDataBase(SQLiteDatabase db) throws SQLException {     

          //Open the database       
          String myPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + DATABASE_NAME;  

          db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);     
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare DB_PATH value in constructor and use it whenever you want so you dont need to assign every time

```
public DBHandler(Context context)
{

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "/.folder name/" + File.separator;

    File f = new File(DB_PATH);
    f.mkdirs();


}
```

and use it as `DB_PATH+DATABASE_NAME` to perform database operation

Comment: getting error in this line this.myContext = context;

Comment: have you declare myContext as global variable.?

Comment: ya got it worked...Thanks..@Sanket Kachhela...and also have a doubt that it is possible to transfer sqlite db data to sql server 2008..?

Comment: yes you can do through via webservices or uploading csv file on to server and server code add that csv file data into his sql server 2008 database

Comment: is there any tutorial or blog available to view this example..im really very new to these process...thanks in advance

Comment: follow this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/a/4126746/942224

Comment: this is using webservice ???? i need without webservice frnd...!