# Uploading file from android (java) to server using PHP

Tags: java, php, android

Hello Im trying to upload files from my android application to my server using PHP.

I have read this posts:

[How to upload a file using Java HttpClient library working with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pr)
http://www.veereshr.com/Java/Upload
[How do I send a file in Android from a mobile device to server using http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126625/how-to-send-a-file-in-android-from-mobile-to-server-using-http?lq=1)

This is my JAVA code:

```
public void upload() throws Exception {

        File file = new File("data/data/com.tigo/databases/exercise");

        Log.i("file.getName()", file.getName());

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://***.***.***.***/backDatabase.php");

        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity( new FileInputStream(file), -1);
        reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");    

        reqEntity.setChunked(true);
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        if((response.getStatusLine().toString()).equals("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")){
            // Successfully Uploaded
            Log.i("uploaded", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        }
        else{
            // Did not upload. Add your logic here. Maybe you want to retry.
            Log.i(" not uploaded", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        }

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php


    $uploads_dir = '/tigo/databaseBackup';

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['exercise']['tmp_name']))
    {

    $info =  "File ". $_FILES['exercise']['name'] ." uploaded successfully.\n";
    $file = 'emailTest.log';
    file_put_contents($file, $info, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

    move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['exercise'] ['tmp_name'], $_FILES['exercise'] ['name']);

    } 
    else 
    {

    $info =  "Possible file upload attack: ";
    $file = 'emailTest.log';
    file_put_contents($file, $info, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

    $info =  "filename '". $_FILES['exercise']['tmp_name'] . "'.";
    file_put_contents($file, $info, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

    print_r($_FILES);

    }

?>
```

In my logcat i get HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
When i look at the server logs i get this error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: exercise in /var/www/backDatabase.php on line 23
```

I also tried to use:

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name']
```

Instead of

```
$_FILES['exercise']['tmp_name']
```

And i got the same error in my server logs.

I think my problem is that I cant get reference to my uploaded file.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4):

try multipart entity

```
public void upload(String filepath) throws IOException
    {
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url");
     File file = new File(filepath);
     MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
     ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
     mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile); 
     httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
     System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             // check the response and do what is required
      }
```

Comment: don''t you need to create the `FileInputStream` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**JAVA code:**

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class UploadFile {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://***.***.***.***/backDatabase.php");
File file = new File("/data/data/com.tigo/databases/exercise");

MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file);
mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);

httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
if (resEntity != null) {
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
}
if (resEntity != null) {
resEntity.consumeContent();
}

httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
}
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php  
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) { 
  echo "File ". $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ." uploaded successfully.\n";
  move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['userfile'] ['tmp_name'], $_FILES['userfile'] ['name']); 
}  else  { 
   echo "Possible file upload attack: "; 
  echo "filename '". $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] . "'.";
 print_r($_FILES); }
 ?>
```

You may need to change the paths in order to fit your needs, but the above code works.

Comment: Hi, i get this error. The constructor FileBody(File, String) is undefined

Comment: add to build_path : http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/httpmime/httpmime-4.2.5.jar.zip

Answer (score -1):

#### Upload Image on Web Server using Android / C# {Xamarin}

> This is Just Small Piece of Code. it can send any image from Android to your Web
>   Server using Android

```
System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient();
Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
byte[] result = Client.UploadFile("localhost/FolderName/upload.php", "POST", path);
string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
```

> Here is the PHP Code {upload.php}. Create a Folder name { Uploads } in
>   your Application.

```
<?php

   $uploads_dir = 'uploads/'; //Directory to save the file that comes from client application.      
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)       
   {      
     $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];     
     $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];    
     move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");     
   }
?>
```