# Upload Image From Android to ASp.net Server

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to upload image fromandroid to asp.net server.
I am following following procedure.
convert image from bitmap to byte[] yhen byte[] to string and pass this string to the asp.net web service 
is this correct way to save image on to the .net server
Please Give the solution to upload image from android to asp.net server 
both client and server side code .

Comment: Yes, it's the correct way to save image on the server.

Comment: but i am not able to save image on to the server

Comment: Are you experiencing problems with any step of your solution? If so, please ask specifically about them.

Comment: is the web service being called? Do the correct bytes arrive? do you receive an exception in your Android app?

Comment: problem is that i am passing parameter string to the .net web service   it says that to much length.

Comment: How are you calling the web service? Do you encode the whole file into a string and pass it as a HTTP GET parameter?

Comment: yes encoded string pass to the web service ..

Comment: call web service using json parser

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is convert your bitmap to `base64` string :

```
public String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image)
{
    Bitmap immagex=image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

    return imageEncoded;
}
```

after converting ,you can send the string to webservice, on the server side, you must decode this string to an image !
To convert base64 to image on server side,**`duckduckgo`** or google will help you :

https://duckduckgo.com

https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&btnG=Search&q=convert+base64+to+image+ASp.net+Server

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318425) by Microsoft - you'll be able to use the `Build the Web Service` part for the web service.

For the Android part, you can get inspired by all other questions that try to send a POST request - for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126625/how-to-send-a-file-in-android-from-mobile-to-server-using-http).

Answer (score 0):

If not too late, here is my suggested solution:

- Server side: you can create a web service or RESTful application on the .NET Framework. Microsoft provides ASP.NET Web API. You can start from [their website here](http://www.asp.net/web-api)
- Client side: your Android here. You can refer to some of the following: [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)...

If you want to use Volley, you can refer to some following links:

- [Working POST Multipart Request with Volley and without HttpEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity)
- [How to send a “multipart/form-data” POST in Android with Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley/)
- [Trouble Sending Multipart File with Boundary via Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187450/trouble-sending-multipart-file-with-boundary-via-volley)

Of course, you can find more available in SO.

Hope this helps!