# MultipartEntity Android always return server error

Tags: android, httpclient, multipartform-data, multipartentity

I have two days facing a problem sending Multipart form request that include data and images, and server always give me error "Unsupported Media Type"

I have tried 3 version of apache httpclient which are (4.1, 4.3, 4.5)

Here is my code

```
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multipartEntity.addTextBody("CategoryId", String.valueOf(categoryId), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
multipartEntity.addBinaryBody("PrimaryImage", primaryImage, ContentType.create("image/jpeg") , "test.jpg");
```

I have added the following headers

```
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Content-Disposition","form-data");
request.setHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
request.setHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

I am using POST Request with Digest Authentication

When I print the content of multipart form request I found the following data

```
--2gj-9i6ivyDT_6wE0ck0DTKUV_hwUu-6m7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CategoryId"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

1

--2gj-9i6ivyDT_6wE0ck0DTKUV_hwUu-6m7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="PrimaryImage"; filename="test.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

����-�Exif
```

The server is keep sending me error and server admin told me that the server can't parse form-data and that the format of my request is wrong

can anyone help please

**EDIT 1**

When I remove the headers from my request and remove the image also the server is able to read all text parameter.

When I remove the headers from my request and keep sending then image I got SocketTimeoutException.

I don't know what is the problem

Comment: Have you tried 'builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)' yet? Moreover, you can refer to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32187557/4328123)

Comment: @BNK I was using it before with version 4.1 and no effect, I will try it with 4.3 and see what will change.

Comment: I updated my above comment

Comment: I have tried it and still giving SocketTimeoutException when I add image, otherwise it work.

Comment: How do you post to server? I think you should post more code here for more information

Comment: And post your full logcat :-)

Comment: Do not set a header to accept json.

Comment: @greenapps Thanks a lot I have removed all headers, and increase request timeout to be 5 minutes, and it is now working.

Comment: Do not set a request timeout.