# Sending files from a mobile application to a server?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am currently making a smart phone application in Java, and this application would require sending files from the smart phone to a server that is running Ubuntu 12.04.

What would be the best way to go about doing this? I have come across many ways, but which would be the easiest to implement? Is there source code that already exists for this that I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Use a web-service. The easiest way is making a web-server level application on your remote server that would process everything you need to send from your app. This is quite easy to achieve, since you might use `POST HTTP` requests or even using directly `Socket`s to send info to your server and the server side just process it in the way you implement it in your favourite language (PHP, Python, Ruby...).

- [Sending files to a remote server via Sockets](http://lakjeewa.blogspot.com.es/2012/03/simple-android-application-to-send-file.html)
- [How do I send a file in Android from a mobile device to server using http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126625/how-to-send-a-file-in-android-from-mobile-to-server-using-http)