# How to send Image file with other parameters using HttpGet method in android?

Tags: android, http-get

I need to upload image file on Server using HttpGet Method.Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: You have to use httpPost request.

Answer (score 0):

use http post request ...convert image to byte array and then send it to server

```
InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("image.png");
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest =
new HttpPost("http://webserver.com/doSomething.do");
byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
InputStreamBody isb = new InputStreamBody(new
ByteArrayInputStream(data), "uploadedFile");
StringBody sb1 = new StringBody("some text goes here");
StringBody sb2 = new StringBody("some text goes here too");
MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity();
multipartContent.addPart("uploadedFile", isb);
multipartContent.addPart("one", sb1);
multipartContent.addPart("two", sb2);
postRequest.setEntity(multipartContent);
HttpResponse response =httpClient.execute(postRequest);
response.getEntity().getContent().close();
```

Answer (score 0):

As already hinted by Nitesh, in order to upload image file you should use a Post request and submit your file as binary.

Please refer below link in SO for more details:
[How do I send a file in Android from a mobile device to server using http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126625/how-to-send-a-file-in-android-from-mobile-to-server-using-http)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  String _URL =https://194.1.3.9:7721/request?image_byte=iamge _inbyte;
 HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
 HttpPost request = new HttpPost(_URL);
 HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

     private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        if (mHttpClient == null) {
            mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        }
        return mHttpClient;     
    }
```

Comment: Very funny to try to put bytes in an url and then do an empty post. Very funny indeed.