# Upload pdf file from android to php

Tags: android, file-upload

I want to upload pdf or doc file from android device to php.
 I got the filePath in onActivityResult method.

```
Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
 String path = selectedFileUri.getPath();
```

I want to know that if there is any method by which I can send file to server? Iam sending image file to server by encoding it to base64 but how can I upload pdf or doc.

Comment: It is normal file upload operation. Are you using any php framework on server side? Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/4126746/3843374

Comment: yes i am using php on server side . I can deal with it. But I want to know that what should I send from android device

Comment: `Iam sending image file to server by encoding it to base64 but how can I upload pdf or doc.`. You do not have to change anything of your code. At least if you did not use Bitmap or BitmapFactory to upload that image file. A file is just a file so it works always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send it as byte array btw

```
String url = "http://yourserver";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
        "yourfile");
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
            new FileInputStream(file), -1);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //Do something with response...

} catch (Exception e) {
    // show error
}
```

And in your php file you can get it with $_FILES.
If you want to add the value name then you can use multipart

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://***.***.***.***/upload.php");
File file = new File("/sdcard/randyka.pdf");

MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file);
mpEntity.addPart("your_file", cbFile);

httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
```

And your php will be like

```
<?php $_FILES['your_file']?>
```

Comment: I have full file path in android. Where can I put it that. Suppse "mnt/sdcard/documents/file.pdf"

Comment: `File file = new File("mnt/sdcard/documents/file.pdf");`

Comment: can i send it with namevaluepair

Comment: your file name. i.e your file name is Randyka.pdf then `$_FILES['randyka.pdf']`

Comment: last question. How can I get filename from path??? Please tell me, I am about to complete

Comment: filename from path? what do you mean?

Comment: means I have file path in android side.. I am selecting the file from file manager. so the name is not same every time

Comment: okay got it now.. Thanks for your precious time buddy. Your help is appreciated

Comment: multipartentity<< cannot find symbol

Comment: yes, you need a library for that. you can find it here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmime426jar.htm

Answer (score 1):

We have used `Retrofit Library` for uploading PDF file on Server. This is the best way to upload PDF file in android programmatically.

**This is the Interface declaration:**

```
@POST("/api/uploadcontroller)

Response uploadPdf(@Body TypedFile file);
```

**Make the call in RestAdapter of the Retrofit API:->**

```
restAdapter.create(RestApiInterface.class) // ^ interface

.uploadPdf(new TypedFile(“application/pdf”, //MIME TYPE
                            new File(pdfFilePath)));// File
```