# Send recorded audio from Android SD Card to external folder

Tags: php, android, audio

I would like to know if it is possible to create a audio recording, put the recorded file inside a directory, and transfere this file to a folder, outside the phone, via HTTP.

I built a PHP file that receives the address from the file, and saves it to a folder:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_GET['url']);                                                
$fp = fopen('file_name.3gpp', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

My Java activity to record audio:

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + File.separator + "record");
directory.mkdirs();

outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
        + "record" + "/record.3gpp";

myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
```

Now I would like to get the directory from the recorded audio, and send it using GET.

It would look like this:

```
http://localhost/folder/record.php?url=DIRECTORY FROM THE AUDIO
```

How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a file to server just like that, you need to `post` or in other words `upload` the file as binary. See this stackoverflow question for how to do that:

[How do I send a file in Android from a mobile device to server using http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126625/how-to-send-a-file-in-android-from-mobile-to-server-using-http)