# Reading Text File From Android on Server (send stream from android)

Tags: android, android-studio, stream

I have a text file on my android device. I need to send this text file from the Android to a web server, using an http request, displaying the content.
Is that case for a stream? I don't know how to send the entire file

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help:

**API 22:** Using HttpClient and "binary/octet-stream"

[How to send a file in Android from mobile to server using http?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126746/850347)

**API23:** Using HttpUrlConnection

[Sending files using POST with HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection)

Or, you can use Retrofit. It is powerful, robust, easy http library.

Tutorial: https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-how-to-upload-files

Comment: OK, I added link of example using HttpUrlConnection(above API23.) But I suggest you to use Retrofit, it is much better.

Comment: I can't understand what do I have to change.. Please help

Comment: Oh I think you need to upload your text file. Can you show me you code?

Comment: I copied the code that you linked me, compatible with API23

Comment: And, did it worked? Let me show your code, then I can understand where is the troubling point.