# Upload any file to server

Tags: java, android

I want to write a function that will upload any filev to my server. I've searched all over the internet but have found nothing useful without using any external libraries. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send a file in Android from a mobile device to server using http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126625/how-do-i-send-a-file-in-android-from-a-mobile-device-to-server-using-http)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri, String destUri)
{
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "uploading file: " + sourceFileUri);

    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile() && !sourceFile.exists())
    {
        Log.e(YOUR_TAG, "Source File not exist :" + imagepath);
        return 0;

    } else {

        try
        {
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(destUri);
            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("file", fileName);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
            Log.i(YOUR_TAG, "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200)
            {
                Log.d(YOUR_TAG, "success: " + sourceFileUri);
                //do your stuff here
            }
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(YOUR_TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(YOUR_TAG, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);

        }
        return serverResponseCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "f_url") //Adding file
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token) //Adding token
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```