# Upload Images to Server

Tags: java, php, file-upload, http-post

I have few images that I want to upload to my server. The client side is written in Java, and I will be making a HTTP Post request to upload images. Do I need to write server side code to handle the http post request? If so, where can I find some examples? The server supports PHP and Tomcat.

Comment: PHP Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php you may want to add some more detail, though - you are not saying what you are planning to do with the uploads, and whether any kind of authentication is necessary

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pro

Comment: @pekka I have an Android app and I'm uploading the user's images to my server, so they can view them online. All images will be stored in public folder. The server is not behind any authentication at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple to implement in java. You have to implement HTTP servlet that overrrides doPost() method that reads from input stream obtained from HTTP request and writes to file output stream.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    InputStream in = req.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.jpg");
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

IOUtils is a utility calss from jakarta commons. If you do not want to include this library into your class path here is the source code of `copy()` method:

```
protected static long copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
        throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 
    long count = 0L;
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        count += n;
    }
    return count;
}
```