# How to upload images into my remote server with PHP?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have an android app, that connectos to the remote database with PHP+json

but now, i have to store photos of the users on the remote server. I need to do it storing the URL of the uploaded photo in a row of the USER TABLE. That is not the problem.  The problem is that i have not idea about with a given path of a photo, how to upload it into a dir of the remote server of my app?

as i know, i need two things, a function that connects with a PHP and gives to the PHP the photo, and a PHP that receives the photo and uploads it into a dir of the remote database.

Well....¿can someone help me to do it?

I checked a lot of tutorials of doing this with PHP but i can't find a easy one that how to do it with android+php+mysql, all i am finding is too hard for me.

can someone give me the code i need to do it?

thanks

EDIT:

there does not exist a simple function and a simple PHP code that does it? Simple ones, the examples you are giving me are very hard for my skills with this and i can't apply to my android app and my remote server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Android part, its just straight Java, and there are loads of examples of using `HttpClient` to perform file uploads.

- [How to upload a file using Java HttpClient library working with PHP - strange problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pro)
- [google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sq=httpclient+file+upload+example)

Comment: also i have that link, like the one of the answer of Francesco, and also its too hard for me, please, if you can, give me the code to do it

Comment: @AndroidUser99 Unsurprisingly, I'm not going to write an android app, a PHP app and a DAO layer for you.  I'm happy to point you in the right direction and help when you run into problems, but I really don't have the time to do all your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

For the PHP side: http://it.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php (there are a lot of sample)

For the Android side: [this article](http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/HttpUpload) explains hot to use `DefaultHttpClient` for make and upload via HTTP

Comment: i have that link, its too hard for me, you can't give me the code to do it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't this kind of ready-to-use-code. Try to follow the guides and come back when you stuck on some point